# nm-connection-editor greyed out

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have a fresh install of an Ubuntu 22.04 vm made with hyper-v. In ubuntu, I want to create a bridged connection (to use in a qemu vm). When I type `nm-connection-editor` though all options are greyed out. I can only choose the connection type. 
 I modified `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` (and had to use sudo as both nano and vi said it was read only) and set managed=true. but after reboot the problem persists. Am I missing something? Many thanks in advance for all the help